# Why doesn't my quick sort code work?

Tags: java, quicksort

Can anyone help me with my quick sort code because it doesn't get executed when I give data to it.

I don't get any answer. It's like it goes an infinite loop or something like that.

```
public class Provo {

public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j)
{
    int temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
}

public static int HoarePartition(int m , int d, int[] a)
{ int pivot=a[m];
 int i=m;
 int j=d;

    while(i<j)
    {
        while(a[i]<pivot)
        {i=i+1;}

        while(a[j]>pivot)
        {j=j-1;}

        if(i<j)
         swap(a,i,j);
    }
    swap(a,m,j);

    return j;
}

public static void quicksort(int m, int d, int[] a)
{
    if (m<d)
    { int s=HoarePartition(m,d,a);
        quicksort(m,s-1,a);
        quicksort(s+1,d,a);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try printing out the values of `m` and `d` arguments every time your program enters your `quicksort` function. See if there is a pattern. If `i == m` and `pivot == a[m]` would `(a[i] < pivot)` be true?

Answer (score 1):

This part might be problematic:

```
if(i<j)
  swap(a,i,j);
```

What happens when both `a[i]` and `a[j]` equals the pivot element? That means they'll get swapped, but **neither `lo` nor `hi` will get decremented**, hence resulting in an infinite loop.

Try this:

```
if(i<j)
  swap(a,i++,j--);
```

That basically does a post-increment/decrement, ensuring that `lo` and `hi` get closer after every iteration.

Comment: +1 for pointing this test case....generally you will find codes for quicksort (even in some books that I have read) that do not consider this condition and simply provide OP's version of code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `HoarePartition()` function
the left index i.e. `i` should start searching for a value (greater than pivot) one ahead from the pivot itself.

so statement `int i=m;` should be  `int i=m+1;`

**EDIT:**

Ensuring `while(i<=j)` rather than `while(i<j)` should do the trick

Comment: Hey...excuse me one more time .. i have to order a large nr of data let's say 7500...but first i tried how it works with a small nr for example 10 ...and it get's me : 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
8

the only thing i changed is i=m+1 at the beginning at i-s initialization